# Capture output of cmd query from Wscript.Shell run method

Tags: shell, command-line, wsh

I am using following code to to execute a merge action . This command initiates a child process (manual merge tool) . but using this code child process could not be opened.
But i get error and output streams

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var launch="tf merge $/Alpha/Dev $/Alpha/Main /recursive /version:C4264~C4264";
var cmdRun = WshShell.Exec(launch);
```

But when i use following code,  the child process is initiated . but window closes as soon as operation finishes. But i am not able to get any output or error streams.

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var launch="tf merge $/Alpha/Dev $/Alpha/Main /recursive /version:C4264~C4264";
var cmdRun = WshShell.run(launch,1,1);
```

How can i get output of command line query while still using  Run() method ?????

Answer (score 2):

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var WshExec = WshShell.Exec("nslookup");
var InStream = WshExec.StdIn;
InStream.writeLine("help");
InStream.writeLine("exit");
var OutStream = WshExec.StdOut;
var Str = "";
while (!OutStream.atEndOfStream) {
    Str = Str + OutStream.readAll();
}
WScript.Echo(Str);
```

Comment: i replaced `WScript.Echo(Str);` with `alert(Str);` Voila!